# How to apply a skin to Inno Setup uninstaller with the ISSkin library?

Tags: inno-setup

I know, how to apply a skin with the [ISSkin add-on](http://isskin.codejock.com/) to Inno Setup's installer part, but I can't figure out, how to do the same for the Inno Setup uninstaller.

How can I apply a skin with the [ISSkin add-on](http://isskin.codejock.com/) also to uninstaller ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to extract the `ISSkin.dll` library along with a skin file into a certain directory and keep it stored, unless your user runs the uninstaller. That's because the uninstaller is an application generated by the setup, and so they're just different (uninstaller e.g. doesn't contain files that could be extracted).

You also need to take into account, that if you'll want to have the whole uninstall process to be skinned, you'll need to unload the `ISSkin.dll` library at the very end of the uninstallation process and that will require you to remove the library with a skin file manually. For this, I'd strongly recommend you to use a folder different from the application one, to allow the uninstaller properly remove the application and the rest do by yourself. Here's a script example, which uses for this local application data folder:

You can follow [the commented version of this code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14595416/2) as well.

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

#define SetupSkinPath "{localappdata}\SetupSkin"

[Files]
Source: ISSkinU.dll; DestDir: {#SetupSkinPath}; Flags: uninsneveruninstall
Source: Styles\Office2007.cjstyles; DestDir: {#SetupSkinPath}; Flags: uninsneveruninstall
```

```pascal
[Code]
procedure SetupLoadSkin(lpszPath: string; lpszIniFileName: string);
  external 'LoadSkin@files:ISSkinU.dll stdcall setuponly';
procedure SetupUnloadSkin;
  external 'UnloadSkin@files:ISSkinU.dll stdcall setuponly';
procedure UninstLoadSkin(lpszPath: string; lpszIniFileName: string);
  external 'LoadSkin@{#SetupSkinPath}\ISSkinU.dll stdcall uninstallonly';
procedure UninstUnloadSkin;
  external 'UnloadSkin@{#SetupSkinPath}\ISSkinU.dll stdcall uninstallonly';
function ShowWindow(hWnd: HWND; nCmdShow: Integer): BOOL;
  external 'ShowWindow@user32.dll stdcall';

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Office2007.cjstyles');
  SetupLoadSkin(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Office2007.cjstyles'), 'NormalBlack.ini');    
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  ShowWindow(StrToInt(ExpandConstant('{wizardhwnd}')), SW_HIDE);
  SetupUnloadSkin;
end;

function InitializeUninstall: Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  UninstLoadSkin(ExpandConstant('{#SetupSkinPath}\Office2007.cjstyles'), 
    'NormalBlack.ini');  
end;

procedure DeinitializeUninstall;
begin
  UninstUnloadSkin;
  UnloadDLL(ExpandConstant('{#SetupSkinPath}\ISSkinU.dll'));
  DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{#SetupSkinPath}\ISSkinU.dll'));
  DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{#SetupSkinPath}\Office2007.cjstyles'));
  RemoveDir(ExpandConstant('{#SetupSkinPath}'));
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much TLama, worked very well. Can you show me how can i create a Label on the unistaller? PagenameLabel, PageDescriptionLabel, StatusLabel and FilenameLabel.

Comment: You're welcome! To your quite off-topic question from comment. The first three labels are already there, look at the [`TUninstallProgressForm`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm#TUninstallProgressForm) class reference and what's inside. With that `FilenameLabel` I think you've been thinking of the `StatusLabel`. If your question is related more on how to create your own label somewhere on your uninstaller form, then I would compare this to installer, except that you'll use instead of the `WizardForm` object the `UninstallProgressForm` to access the form.

Comment: Ok my friend, i will follow your tips and return soon.

Comment: Ok. I forgot to mention on thing; you'll need to do this in the [`InitializeUninstallProgressForm`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm#InitializeUninstallProgressForm) event function instead of `InitializeWizard`, which is used for the installer.

Comment: How can i creat the box that you created to show you my script? Sorry my ignorance.

Comment: Paste a code, select it and press `CTRL+K` (or the `{}` button on the post editor toolbar) in the post editor. But please don't change this question to something different. It took me some time to answer this and it might be helpful to someone else in the future. If you have a different question, not related to this one, please ask it separately. Thanks!

Comment: 'Sorry TLama, i will follow your instruction.'

Comment: Those labels appear, but using `clWhite` font on a `clBtnFace` default color makes you think, they don't. Just use a more contrast `Font.Color` for your labels with the `Color` of your uninstall form. Anyway, don't forget on answer accepting (if your initial problem from the original question has been resolved).

Comment: Hi again TLama, now work fine. This is the result. http://s4.postimage.org/bwhxmntxp/Sem_t_tulo.jpg

Comment: `if not (FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\{uninstallexe}'))) then begin` must be the first line after the Event `DeinitializeUninstall`  to keep needed files when a user tries to uninstall and then press "No" in Uninstall Confirmation Message Box.